# converting soapUI basic authentication

Tags: authentication, soap, wsdl, soapui

How does one convert the SoapUI "Basic Authentication" into code so I can make the call from within a program?

I have successfully configured SoapUI to call a soap web service with "Basic Authentication" and return a result. When I say "Basic Authentication", I am simply adding in a username and password to the "Authorization:" drop down in SoapUI.

I would now like to take the same xml code and write a basic program (programming language is irrelevant - will take your suggestion) to do the same thing. I just can't find anything that works.

Thanks

Comment: When there is everything readily available in soapui, why to re-invent the wheel? What are you trying to achieve, what is use case?

Comment: Basic authentication does not use XML. It is set in the headers of HTTP request.

Comment: Rao - I am trying to write a backend app that can be called by a web form so using SoapUI is not an option. I used SoapUI to test the connection to ensure I have formatted the xml correctly etc.

Comment: Sashwat - thanks for your comment. How do I code these HTTP requests as part of the soap web service program? Is it like a standard web type call where I get authenticated and receive a session_id, which I then use to make the soap call? Do you have a small code sample of how to do this. Is there a way to make the HTTP request and then just append the xml file and call the soap service?

Comment: @user1398017 you need to choose a soap client first(eg cxf). Then you can use the its native API or jaxws api(assuming client is in java) to add the authentication to soap header assuming that ws security of type username/password is being used on the server side